# BigQuery errors: Missing rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to using bigquery streaming my data by using python, while this error occur. Is there any clue that why does this happen?
[image]

Comment: here's my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/lihh8z7cbgmzhwm/bigquery_single_rssi.py?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by remove `input_row = json.dumps(input_row)` from my main function, my input_row is a dict (python2.7). I guess the possible problem is the format different.